# How to add CDO reference in an asp web page

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message, cdonts

I'm trying to create a new email in asp and send it to a mail server using CDO.  I believe I need a reference for CDO or Send Email functionality.  In the book it says use this:

```
Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
```

Unfortunately that is now working as it errors out in asp.  Now sure how to add the reference, or com object so that it will work through iis using asp.  The book I'm referring to is: ASP In a nut shell 2nd addition. "The CDO Object Model"  I'm using windows xp or windows server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of cdonts

```
<!--
    METADATA        
    TYPE="typelib"        
    UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D"        
    NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Library"
-->

<%
Function SendMail(sFrom, ToA, Subject, Mybody)

     Dim iMsg,iConf      
     Set iMsg  = CreateObject("CDO.Message")         
     Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

     Dim Flds        
     Set Flds = iConf.Fields    
     With Flds       
       ' assume constants are defined within script file       
       .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod)   = cdoSendUsingPort          
       .Item(cdoSMTPServer)        = MAILSERVER        
       .Item(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 60            
       .Item(cdoURLGetLatestVersion)   = True          
       .Update         
     End With

     With iMsg       
       Set .Configuration = iConf          
           .To       = ToA             
           .From     = sFrom               
           .Subject  = Subject             
           .TextBody = Mybody              
           .Send               
     End With

     Set iConf = nothing         
     Set iMsg = nothing

    If Err.Number = 0 Then      
      SendMail = True           
    Else        
     SendMail = Err.Number&":"&Err.Description          
    End If
    On Error Goto 0    
    set objSendMail = Nothing       
End Function    

%>
```